# Why DSolve solution to this PDE does not match NDSolve solution?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I was answering different question [How Can I Visualize a PDE Boundary Condition?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256175/how-can-i-visualize-a-pde-boundary-condition) and in the process, found that `DSOlve` solution to the laplace PDE does not agree with the BC.

Then I tried `NDSolve` and the plot now shows agreement.

Did I do something wrong here, or could this be a bug in `DSolve`?

First, here is plot of the BC on its own

```
ClearAll [theta, r, u]
bcf = 2*Pi*theta - theta^2;
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], bcf}, {r, 1 - .01, 
  1 + .01}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence the solution to the PDE should match the above on the BC. But it does not:

```
ClearAll [theta, r, u]
pde = Laplacian[u[r, theta], {r, theta}, "Polar"] == 0;
bcf = 2*Pi*theta - theta^2;
bc = u[1, theta] == bcf;
sol = u[r, theta] /. First@DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[r, theta], {r, theta}];
sol = sol /. K[1] -> n;
sol = sol /. Infinity -> 50 (*more than enough terms*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting the solution with the BC together shows mismatch on some interval

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], Activate[sol]}, {r, 0, 
   1}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.6], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], bcf}, {r, 1 - 0.1, 
   1 + 0.1}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now compare with `NDSolve` for same PDE and same BC

```
solNumerical = 
 First@NDSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], 
   Evaluate[u[r, theta] /. solNumerical]}, {r, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, 
   2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], bcf}, {r, 1 - 0.1, 
   1 + 0.1}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is going on? Why `DSolve` solution does not agree with BC? Did I make mistake somewhere?

V 12.3.1 on windows 10

Comment: Looks to me like Mathematica might be taking the range $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ rather than $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$.  Also you didn't apply the BCs correctly;  none of the constants $a_n$ (including $a_0$) should depend on $\theta$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I think you are right, I will remove my hand solution for now. But still, I do not understand why DSolve solution does not agree with BC. Will try with theta from -PI to Pi to see if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `"Polar"` coordinates programmed into Mathematica implicitly assume that the $\theta$ coordinate runs between -π and π, not between 0 and 2π as your initial `ParametricPlot` assumed:

```
CoordinateChartData["Polar", "CoordinateRangeAssumptions"]

(* #1[[1]] > 0 && -\[Pi] < #1[[2]] <= \[Pi] & *)
```

In particular, this means that Mathematica is assuming that the value at the boundary should range from $-3 \pi^2$ as $\theta \to - \pi$ from above all the way to $\pi^2$ as $\theta \to +\pi$ from below.  In other words, it thinks you want this boundary condition:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], bcf}, {r, 1 - .01, 1 + .01}, 
  {theta, -Pi,  Pi}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

(Note the change in the range of `theta` in the plot;  everything else is the same as it was before.)  This is why you see the large discontinuity along the boundary of Mathematica's solution.  It also explains why the plot agrees for points in quadrants I & II (where your definition of $\theta$ agrees with Mathematica's) but disagrees in quadrants III & IV (where you assume that $\pi < \theta < 2 \pi$ but Mathematica is assuming that $-\pi < \theta < 0$.)

To implement the BCs that you originally wanted in a way that is compatible with Mathematica's assumptions about coordinate ranges, you would use:

```
newbcf[theta_] = Piecewise[{{2*Pi*theta - theta^2, 0 <= theta <= Pi}, {-2*Pi*theta - theta^2, -Pi < theta < 0}},0]
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], newbcf[theta]}, {r, 1 - .01, 1 + .01}, 
  {theta, -Pi,  Pi}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Using the same code you used, but with `bcf` replaced with `newbcf[theta]`, yields a solution of

[image]

and plotting this using your code (changing the range of $\theta$ to run from -π to π) yields a correct-looking plot:

[image]

Comment: What's the explanation for why Mathematica is even using `"Polar"` coordinates in the first place? With no boundary conditions given for `theta`, it just assumes that periodic boundary conditions are desired?

Comment: @Carmeister:  `"Polar"` is invoked in the OP's attempt to use `DSolve`: `pde = Laplacian[u[r, theta], {r, theta}, "Polar"] == 0`.  I would assume that internally, this is equivalent to saying that `u` satisfies the Laplacian in polar coordinates *and* that there are period boundary conditions that match the $\theta = -\pi$ and $\theta = \pi$ lines.  In contrast, in the second solution (with `NDSolve`), the OP explicitly wrote out the Laplacian in polar coordinates and provided the boundary conditions they wanted.

Comment: The `"Polar"` there isn't an input to `DSolve` though: it just gives the Laplacian in polar coordinates. The output is `(Derivative[0, 2][u][r, theta]/r + Derivative[1, 0][u][r, theta])/r + 
  Derivative[2, 0][u][r, theta]` with no reference to polar coordinates anymore.

Comment: @Carmeister:  ....  Hmm.  That's a darn good point.  I'll have to think on that.

Comment: After doing a bit of experimenting, it seems Mathematica will make some assumptions about your region/boundary conditions for some simple cases, including this one. For example `DSolve[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, u[x, 0] == 1/(1 + x^2)}, u[x, y], {x, y}]` will happily assume that the desired region is the upper half-plane and solve the PDE there, but it balks if the boundary condition is replaced by `u[x, 1] == 1/(1 + x^2)}` unless I explicitly give it a region. I'm not sure if this behavior is documented anywhere.